# django - Getting an error after passing on_delete argument

Tags: django-models

Creating a game model in django 2.0, by passing `on_delete` arg in foreign key as well.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Game(models.Model):
    first_player = models.ForeignKey(User,
                                     related_name="games_first_player")
    second_player = models.ForeignKey(User,
                                      related_name="games_second_player")

    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_active = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Creating a Move model

```
class Move(models.Model):
    x = models.IntegerField()
    y = models.IntegerField()
    comment = models.charfield(max_length=300, blank=True)
    by_first_player = models.BooleanField()

    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You forgot to specify `on_delete`s for `first_player` and `second_player`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot th specify the [**`on_delete=...`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) of your `ForeignKey`s in your `Game` model:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Game(models.Model):
    first_player = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        related_name='games_first_player',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    second_player = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        related_name='games_second_player'
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_active = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

You might want to use [**`get_user_model()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model) over `User`, since if you later change your user model, you can easily update all `ForeignKey`s.

Comment: Thanks, willem I got it now!!